# While designing a webpage getting issues with layout stuff( 1600 X 900 pixels)

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working on website and designing a master page gave some fixed pixels to table layout but getting issues while seeing that page on 1600 X 900 pixels. Then trying into percentage stuff.

create a table and divide that table into columns and gave 40% to first and last column (to st background) because i want my main content table into middle of the screen and gave hardcoded 970px but still getting issues with layout stuff. Last column looks 60% of total screen.

can we set column width dynamically depends on screen resolution ? or some specific solution please suggest..

Comment: Is it kind of wrong question ? why you vote up -1 ? This is the platform where we discuss our problems. I am getting it so asked a question...huh

Comment: UI design is not really SO's area.. I've flagged for a moderator with a suggestion of a move to UX SE.

Comment: @TechGiant: I think because you're question it's not really clear. You should try to explain better what you're trying to do and maybe include your actual code, and a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: I agree, the title is misleading and the question is badly worded.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the HTML that you are using, and an image of what you want the results to look like?

Comment: Yeah guys i think you are right i will update this question with attached screen shot.. and code.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="background-color: Black; width: 100%; height: 680px;">
    <div style="width: 970px; margin: 0 auto;padding:0px">
        <div style="width: 25%; height: 675px; float: left; background-color: Blue;">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 75%; height: 675px; float: right; background-color: white">
            <div style="width: 75%; height: 675px; float: left; background-color: red">
            </div>
            <div style="width: 25%; height: 675px; float: right; background-color: Green">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

---

Hope it helps

Comment: Exor, You are correct can i achieve this using table, I've tried same code in table and used some images as to maintain gradient but worked on Mozilla but in IE it doesn't work.

Comment: @TechGiant : Yea should be possible. can you send me your code.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries could solve your problem, take a look at this:

[CSS3 Media Queries](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries)

You can use different CSS depending on the screen resolution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With tables

---

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="background-color: Black; width: 100%; height: 680px;">
 <div style="width: 970px; margin:0 auto;padding:0px">
 <table width="100%" style="margin:0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <colgroup width="100%">
 <col width="25%" />
 <col width="50%" />
 <col width="25%" />
 </colgroup>
 <tr>
 <td style="height:680px; background-color:Aqua">

 </td>
 <td style="height:680px; background-color:Green">
 </td>
 <td style="height:680px; background-color:Maroon">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```